# I want to know if there is the clothing object class in the MS COCO dataset?

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I want to do something about clothing segmentation, so I need to train the network  on dataset which has the clothing class.
Anyone can answer me? I do not find something about classes in the http://mscoco.org/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find the object instance categories of coco in the instance annotation json files (can be found in the [download](http://mscoco.org/dataset/#download) page).
Download and read the file, you'll see the annotated categories:

```
In [1]: import json    
In [2]: with open('./instances_val2014.json','r') as R:
   ...:     js = json.loads(R.read())
   ...:
In [3]: js.keys()
Out[3]: [u'info', u'images', u'licenses', u'annotations', u'categories']
In [4]: js['categories']
Out[4]:
[{u'id': 1, u'name': u'person', u'supercategory': u'person'},
 {u'id': 2, u'name': u'bicycle', u'supercategory': u'vehicle'},
 {u'id': 3, u'name': u'car', u'supercategory': u'vehicle'},
 {u'id': 4, u'name': u'motorcycle', u'supercategory': u'vehicle'},
 {u'id': 5, u'name': u'airplane', u'supercategory': u'vehicle'},
 {u'id': 6, u'name': u'bus', u'supercategory': u'vehicle'},
 {u'id': 7, u'name': u'train', u'supercategory': u'vehicle'},
 {u'id': 8, u'name': u'truck', u'supercategory': u'vehicle'},
 {u'id': 9, u'name': u'boat', u'supercategory': u'vehicle'},
 {u'id': 10, u'name': u'traffic light', u'supercategory': u'outdoor'},
 {u'id': 11, u'name': u'fire hydrant', u'supercategory': u'outdoor'},
 {u'id': 13, u'name': u'stop sign', u'supercategory': u'outdoor'},
 {u'id': 14, u'name': u'parking meter', u'supercategory': u'outdoor'},
 {u'id': 15, u'name': u'bench', u'supercategory': u'outdoor'},
 {u'id': 16, u'name': u'bird', u'supercategory': u'animal'},
 {u'id': 17, u'name': u'cat', u'supercategory': u'animal'},
 {u'id': 18, u'name': u'dog', u'supercategory': u'animal'},
 {u'id': 19, u'name': u'horse', u'supercategory': u'animal'},
 {u'id': 20, u'name': u'sheep', u'supercategory': u'animal'},
 {u'id': 21, u'name': u'cow', u'supercategory': u'animal'},
 {u'id': 22, u'name': u'elephant', u'supercategory': u'animal'},
 {u'id': 23, u'name': u'bear', u'supercategory': u'animal'},
 {u'id': 24, u'name': u'zebra', u'supercategory': u'animal'},
 {u'id': 25, u'name': u'giraffe', u'supercategory': u'animal'},
 {u'id': 27, u'name': u'backpack', u'supercategory': u'accessory'},
 {u'id': 28, u'name': u'umbrella', u'supercategory': u'accessory'},
 {u'id': 31, u'name': u'handbag', u'supercategory': u'accessory'},
 {u'id': 32, u'name': u'tie', u'supercategory': u'accessory'},
 {u'id': 33, u'name': u'suitcase', u'supercategory': u'accessory'},
 {u'id': 34, u'name': u'frisbee', u'supercategory': u'sports'},
 {u'id': 35, u'name': u'skis', u'supercategory': u'sports'},
 {u'id': 36, u'name': u'snowboard', u'supercategory': u'sports'},
 {u'id': 37, u'name': u'sports ball', u'supercategory': u'sports'},
 {u'id': 38, u'name': u'kite', u'supercategory': u'sports'},
 {u'id': 39, u'name': u'baseball bat', u'supercategory': u'sports'},
 {u'id': 40, u'name': u'baseball glove', u'supercategory': u'sports'},
 {u'id': 41, u'name': u'skateboard', u'supercategory': u'sports'},
 {u'id': 42, u'name': u'surfboard', u'supercategory': u'sports'},
 {u'id': 43, u'name': u'tennis racket', u'supercategory': u'sports'},
 {u'id': 44, u'name': u'bottle', u'supercategory': u'kitchen'},
 {u'id': 46, u'name': u'wine glass', u'supercategory': u'kitchen'},
 {u'id': 47, u'name': u'cup', u'supercategory': u'kitchen'},
 {u'id': 48, u'name': u'fork', u'supercategory': u'kitchen'},
 {u'id': 49, u'name': u'knife', u'supercategory': u'kitchen'},
 {u'id': 50, u'name': u'spoon', u'supercategory': u'kitchen'},
 {u'id': 51, u'name': u'bowl', u'supercategory': u'kitchen'},
 {u'id': 52, u'name': u'banana', u'supercategory': u'food'},
 {u'id': 53, u'name': u'apple', u'supercategory': u'food'},
 {u'id': 54, u'name': u'sandwich', u'supercategory': u'food'},
 {u'id': 55, u'name': u'orange', u'supercategory': u'food'},
 {u'id': 56, u'name': u'broccoli', u'supercategory': u'food'},
 {u'id': 57, u'name': u'carrot', u'supercategory': u'food'},
 {u'id': 58, u'name': u'hot dog', u'supercategory': u'food'},
 {u'id': 59, u'name': u'pizza', u'supercategory': u'food'},
 {u'id': 60, u'name': u'donut', u'supercategory': u'food'},
 {u'id': 61, u'name': u'cake', u'supercategory': u'food'},
 {u'id': 62, u'name': u'chair', u'supercategory': u'furniture'},
 {u'id': 63, u'name': u'couch', u'supercategory': u'furniture'},
 {u'id': 64, u'name': u'potted plant', u'supercategory': u'furniture'},
 {u'id': 65, u'name': u'bed', u'supercategory': u'furniture'},
 {u'id': 67, u'name': u'dining table', u'supercategory': u'furniture'},
 {u'id': 70, u'name': u'toilet', u'supercategory': u'furniture'},
 {u'id': 72, u'name': u'tv', u'supercategory': u'electronic'},
 {u'id': 73, u'name': u'laptop', u'supercategory': u'electronic'},
 {u'id': 74, u'name': u'mouse', u'supercategory': u'electronic'},
 {u'id': 75, u'name': u'remote', u'supercategory': u'electronic'},
 {u'id': 76, u'name': u'keyboard', u'supercategory': u'electronic'},
 {u'id': 77, u'name': u'cell phone', u'supercategory': u'electronic'},
 {u'id': 78, u'name': u'microwave', u'supercategory': u'appliance'},
 {u'id': 79, u'name': u'oven', u'supercategory': u'appliance'},
 {u'id': 80, u'name': u'toaster', u'supercategory': u'appliance'},
 {u'id': 81, u'name': u'sink', u'supercategory': u'appliance'},
 {u'id': 82, u'name': u'refrigerator', u'supercategory': u'appliance'},
 {u'id': 84, u'name': u'book', u'supercategory': u'indoor'},
 {u'id': 85, u'name': u'clock', u'supercategory': u'indoor'},
 {u'id': 86, u'name': u'vase', u'supercategory': u'indoor'},
 {u'id': 87, u'name': u'scissors', u'supercategory': u'indoor'},
 {u'id': 88, u'name': u'teddy bear', u'supercategory': u'indoor'},
 {u'id': 89, u'name': u'hair drier', u'supercategory': u'indoor'},
 {u'id': 90, u'name': u'toothbrush', u'supercategory': u'indoor'}]
```

As you can see, apart from `'tie'` category, not much clothing there...

On the other hand, you might find [DeepFashion dataset](http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/projects/DeepFashion.html) useful.

Comment: How can I extract some certain classes out of all classes? For example, I want to extract the dog and cat class only. Thanks!

Comment: @Huyen please ask a new question.

Comment: To get all categories as list: `[i['name'] for i in js['categories']]`